# iOS 4.3 uses wrong font in PhoneGap app

Tags: css, ios, ios4, cordova, fonts

I'm porting an existing website to the iPad so it can be used offline and still have pretty fonts. I'm using PhoneGap to do this.

The font family I'm using contains both "regular" and "condensed" versions. The iPad 5.0 Simulator has no problem differentiating between the versions but the iPad 4.3 (simulator and real) seems to prefer the last type defined in [app name]-Info.plist.

So, despite specifying in the CSS that "Blurg-Regular" be used it uses "Blurg-Cond". If I switch the ordering of the fonts then it prefers the "regular" version. Where "Blurg-Cond" is specified "Blurg-Regular" is used instead.

Here's an example of some of the CSS I'm using:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea,
#bd {
   font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular';
}

#hd > h2 {
   font-family: 'MyriadPro-Cond';
}
```

[How I include the fonts.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589848/134014)

iOS 5 is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the fonts in the `www` directory and including them using CSS's `@font-face` solved the problem. Using this method I was able to define the `font-family` name and which font file to use for a specific weight/style. So far I haven't noticed any performance differences between this method and the one I used before.