# Phonegap Windows phone 8 custom web-font

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, windows-phone-8, webfonts

I'm trying to embed a custom font into a WebView in a Windows Phone 8 application and tried everything already. I came across a very promising article: [blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/23/about-webview-and-embedded-fonts.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/23/about-webview-and-embedded-fonts.aspx) but it didn't work out.

Ex:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 35 Light';
   src: url('35-light/avenirltstdlight.eot');
   src: url('35-light/avenirltstdlight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('35-light/avenirltstdlight.woff') format('woff'),
        url('35-light/avenirltstdlight.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('35-light/avenirltstdlight.svg#avenirltstdlight') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Tried also including only the path with:

```
x-wapp0:avenir...woff
```

And even with Base64. What is funny is that opening the app in the browser, everything works fine. I only have problems when it gets embedded into Phonegap.

Can any of you help out or have any pointers about accomplishing this?

Again, on the very end I want to use a custom font (with web icons) into my HTML being shown in an app via Phonegap.

What is even more strange, is that even the embedded woff base64 font is not working.

Thank you

Comment: I have tried this before and there is no way to do it with Phonegap CSS. The only way I can think of is to actually go and modify your Cordova shell application for windows and XCode for iOS and include the fonts there for your application. You need to look for adding fonts to a Windows Phone application or Adding fonts to an iOS application using XCode.

Comment: can you post the CSS snippet in question?

Comment: @SujeshArukil Have any pointers to give? You mean like "installing" the font somehow into the app?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324569/adding-ttf-font-to-phonegap-app talks about iOS. But Windows (there are ways through Silverlight) but I haven't found one with Cordova Phonegap.

Comment: @SujeshArukil in IOS webfonts work perfectly fine. Only on this %$#! WP8 that doesn't.

Comment: Wait.. WP8? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_WindowsPhonefonts supports embedded type fonts. Give me some time, let me see if I can find a resource for you.

Comment: http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2012/windows-8-xaml-tips-custom-fonts this should help you. I found this link through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085818/custom-font-usage-in-windows-phone-8 Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TTFEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ttfedit/) to set the embeddable tag on the font to 0. That should fix it, but make sure you have the rights to embed the font before selling your app.

My [full answer to a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558331/getting-a-web-font-to-work-on-an-html5-windows-phone-app/20573678#20573678) question might help too.

Comment: This is the right answer. I created a repo with a sample app based on @thomasf2811 solution: https://github.com/gabrielmaldi/windows-phone-8-local-font-face

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and this resolved my problem:                     http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-easiest-way-to-use-any-font-you-wish--net-3927